# Weblogic 12.2.1.3 InvalidJarIndexException

Tags: groovy, weblogic

I'm having a huge issue with Weblogic 12.2.1.3 trying to deploy an application which, by the way, deploys fine to Weblogic 12.1.3. There seems to be some kind of incompatibilities with libraries used by Weblogic 12.2.1.3. I have tried adding preferred packages but no success yet. I'm posting below the stack trace showing this exception. Please comment any ideas on this:

```
####<May 21, 2018 10:47:18,491 AM EDT> <Error> <Console> <EADCDRITSP2429> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <system> <> <5d345739-6009-4af0-b810-114da13abb45-00000034> <1526914038491> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException: Invalid index:sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException:Invalid index
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1140)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1050)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:239)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:365)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doParentDelegate(GenericClassLoader.java:584)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:526)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:473)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doParentDelegate(GenericClassLoader.java:584)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:526)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:473)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doParentDelegate(GenericClassLoader.java:584)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:526)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:473)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doParentDelegate(GenericClassLoader.java:584)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:526)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:473)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doParentDelegate(GenericClassLoader.java:584)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:526)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:72)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:676)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:544)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:183)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToOuter(ResolveVisitor.java:661)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveFromStaticInnerClasses(ResolveVisitor.java:404)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveFromStaticInnerClasses(ResolveVisitor.java:404)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveFromStaticInnerClasses(ResolveVisitor.java:404)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1202)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:146)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$11.call(CompilationUnit.java:648)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:928)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:590)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:539)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:297)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:267)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:692)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:704)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:740)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:731)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator.run(GafferConfigurator.groovy:71)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator$run.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:161)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator.run(GafferConfigurator.groovy:44)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferUtil.runGafferConfiguratorOn(GafferUtil.java:43)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:67)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:145)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:328)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.addStatus(StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.java:32)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.addInfo(StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.java:20)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(LogbackServletContainerInitializer.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializer(WebAppServletContext.java:1404)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1364)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1345)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1917)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3101)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1843)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:884)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTu`enter code here`ningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem was solved by adding -Djava.system.class.loader=com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader to the startup arguments

Comment: It seems like this fixes my problem as well! How did you come up with it? What are the, eventual, consequences?